# How to use RSA and public key encryption between a client (holding the encrypted text) and a server (holding the private key)?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have looked into public key encryption and I have created a class which creates a public key and private key. Code ->

```
    public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

public static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "C:/keys/private.key";

public static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "C:/keys/public.key";

public RSAKey() {
    try {

        // Check if the pair of keys are present else generate those.
        if (!areKeysPresent()) {
            // Method generates a pair of keys using the RSA algorithm and stores it
            // in their respective files
            generateKey();
        }

        final String originalText = "ip=182324289428&id=249019";
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

        // Encrypt the string using the public key
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE));
        final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
        final byte[] cipherText = encrypt(originalText, publicKey);

        // Decrypt the cipher text using the private key.
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
        final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject();
        final String plainText = decrypt(cipherText, privateKey);

        // Printing the Original, Encrypted and Decrypted Text
        System.out.println("Original: " + originalText);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " +cipherText.toString());
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + plainText);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void generateKey() {
    try {
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        File privateKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
        File publicKeyFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

        if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
            privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

        if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
            publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

        // Saving the Public key in a file
        ObjectOutputStream publicKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile));
        publicKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPublic());
        publicKeyOS.close();

        // Saving the Private key in a file
        ObjectOutputStream privateKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile));
        privateKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPrivate());
        privateKeyOS.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static boolean areKeysPresent() {

    File privateKey = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
    File publicKey = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

    if (privateKey.exists() && publicKey.exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherText;
}

public static String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) {
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

        // decrypt the text using the private key
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(dectyptedText);
}
```

My question is - could I hold an encrypted string on the client software (which would be like the current version that is being used), send this string to the server, have the server decrypt it using the private key and then have the server check if this string is the current version of the product?

How would I hold the public key on the client and the private key on the server?

Comment: You distribute the public key to all clients, i.e. post it on a website or include it in the client resources (if the client is your code).

Comment: @JimGarrison could I get the public key, encrypt it and just leave the encrypted string on the client software?

Comment: A public key is public, it is pointless to encrypt it.

Comment: @LukePark sorry - I didn't mean encrypt the public key, I meant, hold something like the current version "id" which is ENCRYPTED with the public key, send it to the server, if the server decrypts it and see the id is the same as the server id, then it allows the connection.